# Check if selected text on page has some word in it

Tags: javascript

With the below code I can find the text on a page and highlight it

```
document.designMode = "on";
if(window.find(textLine, true)){  
       document.execCommand("BackColor", false, "rgb(250, 250, 0)");
   textSelection.collapseToEnd();
}
document.designMode = "off";
```

But my requirement is to find text in the selected text. i.e I want to highlight some text if some word is existing in selected text. With the `surroundCountents()` method I can wrap the initial text with some DIV element and then try searching the HTML, but I am looking for a solution that is like the code above. Any suggestions please?

Comment: So you basically want to use window.find to find text within text your already found with window.find(textLine, true).... ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported to use window.find to find text that is already selected from a previous window.find as the window.find method (from what I see) does not support searching in ranges or selections.

API is here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljkjvqqo.php

I suspect you could use window.find again for your keyword and check caret position, etc to verify result is in original result but that seems inefficient on first glace.
Have a look at selection API and ranges... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Selection
You could run 2 window.find and compare the ranges to see the second one is within the first one.

I think a plain simple javascript text search would be quite efficient and fast for what you want.